# How do I make a Bash script run continously, also end it when I want to?

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script that creates a private Geth node named "startnode.sh".

I want to be able to run this script on a server and exit that server without any problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! If I understand correctly, this question probably belongs on [su], but it was easy enough to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for nohup(1).

It is a utility which let's you detach a process from your current terminal session.

Here's a link to a manual of a [FreeBSD nohup(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?nohup).

Comment: Ubuntu man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/nohup.1posix.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, set up a systemd .service file and have it run as a daemon
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd